# How to change the base year of constant dollars

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains the monthly values ($) of building permits, per region, per type of structure. I have them in current dollars and constant 2012 dollars. I would like to change the constant dollars to a base of the most recent month, ie 2021-05.

The Worldbank says this about changing the base year of constant dollars:

> For example, you can rescale the 2010 data to 2005 by first creating an index dividing each year  of the constant 2010 series by its 2005 value (thus, 2005 will equal 1). Then multiply each year's index result by the corresponding 2005 current U.S. dollar price value.

My table looks something like this (in reality, there are many cities, each having many types of structures, eg: Residential, institutional, etc.):

```
Period      City        Type of structure    Value     valueAdjustment
2011-01-01  New York    Commercial, total    125478    Current Dollars
2011-01-01  New York    Commercial, total    129276    Constant dollars
2011-02-01  New York    Commercial, total    120568    Current Dollars
2011-02-01  New York    Commercial, total    124110    Constant dollars
...
2021-04-01  New York    Commercial, total    197296    Current Dollars
2021-04-01  New York    Commercial, total    154500    Constant dollars
2021-05-01  New York    Commercial, total    155043    Current Dollars
2021-05-01  New York    Commercial, total    121082    Constant dollars
```

What I've thought of doing is to create a column, `Rank`, to then use some variation of `ROW_NUMBER` to easily compare every month to 2021-05. I populated the rank like such:

```
WITH cteRank AS(
       SELECT t.*,
         Rnk = DENSE_RANK()OVER (ORDER BY YEAR([Period]), DATEPART(MONTH,[Period]) ) 
         - COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([Period]) = 2021 AND DATEPART(MONTH,[Period])=2 THEN 1 END) OVER ()
         - 1 +836
       FROM [buildingPermits] t)
UPDATE cteRank SET [Rank] = Rnk FROM cteRank ;
```

The +836 is because with the way I coded it, it counts every instance of 2021-05, so I added the count to cancel it out. Not very efficient, but it works.

The resulting Rank column looks like this:

```
Period      Rank   City        Type of structure    Value      valueAdjustment
2011-01-01  -124   New York    Commercial, total    125478     Current Dollars
2011-01-01  -124   New York    Commercial, total    129276     Constant dollars
2011-02-01  -123   New York    Commercial, total    120568     Current Dollars
2011-02-01  -123   New York    Commercial, total    124110     Constant dollars
...
2021-04-01  -1     New York    Commercial, total    197296     Current Dollars
2021-04-01  -1     New York    Commercial, total    154500     Constant dollars
2021-05-01  0      New York    Commercial, total    155043     Current Dollars
2021-05-01  0      New York    Commercial, total    121082     Constant dollars
```

The last step is the Worldbank's formula adapted to my need:

> For example, you can rescale the 2012 data to 2021-05 by first creating an index dividing each year of the constant 2012 series by its 2021-05 value (thus, 2021-05 will equal 1). Then multiply each year's index result by the corresponding 2021-05 current U.S. dollar price value.

So for 2011-01, it would be:

```
(Constant 2011-01) / (Constant 2021-05) * (Current 2021-05)
     129276        /      121082        *      155043

=165535
```

Here's some pseudo code for the division using a subquery, but it obviously returns an error because I didn't target specific cities and Type of Structure. Partitioning returned an error as well, `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'`

```
SELECT Period, [Type of structure],City, 
    Value/ (SELECT Value 
            FROM [buildingPermits] 
            WHERE YEAR(Period) = 2021 
                 and DATEPART(MONTH,Period) = 5  
                 and valueAdjustment= 'Constant dollars' and  [Rank] = 0) 
FROM [buildingPermits] 
WHERE valueAdjustment= 'Constant dollars'
```

```
Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= 
or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I think a `SELF JOIN`, a temp table, subquery or somehow using `MAX(Rank)` to get the value at rank 0 (2021-05) could do the trick, but I don't know how to go about implementing either of those solutions.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this get you closer to what you want?

```
SELECT Const201101.[Period], Const201101.City, Const201101.[Type of structure],
                Const201101.[Value] as [Const 201101 Value],
                Const202105.[Value] as [Const 202105 Value],
                Curr202105.[Value]  as [Curr 202105 Value]
FROM [buildingPermits] Const201101
    JOIN [buildingPermits] Const202105 ON
                    Const202105.City                = Const201101.City                  AND
                    Const202105.[Type of structure] = Const201101.[Type of structure]   AND
                    Const202105.[Period]            = '2021-05'                         AND
                    Const202105.valueAdjustment     = 'Constant dollars'
    JOIN [buildingPermits] Curr202105 ON
                    Curr202105.City                 = Const201101.City                  AND
                    Curr202105.[Type of structure]  = Const201101.[Type of structure]   AND
                    Curr202105.[Period]             = '2021-05'                         AND
                    Curr202105.valueAdjustment      = 'Current Dollars'
WHERE Const201101.valueAdjustment= 'Constant dollars' AND Const201101.[Period] = '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: That might! Thank you